# Angular 2 adsense, insufficient content

Tags: angular, adsense, systemjs

I've received an Adsense rejection due to insufficient content in this website: http://diasbajalaboral.com.

This is an Angular app. It has a delay of 2-3 seconds loading the content and also the ads (due to systemjs loading angular2.min.js). The website has almost 1.100 words explaining how does "work incapacity" work in Spain. Also has a form that allows the user to make some simulations.

What should I do to get approved? Would removing Angular 2 and transforming it to plain HTML solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be the lack of external and internal links on your website. Fixing this would mean a completely different approach on your site.

Another issue could be that the loading of your page takes way too long. Try minifying your JS/CSS.

Try serving your content with gzip by adding this to your `nginx.conf` on the server

```
gzip on;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript application/octet-stream application/json;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 0;
gzip_comp_level 9;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
```

Perhaps add browser caching as well to the server block in the server configuration:

```
location ~* (\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff)|css)$ {
    expires 1y;
}
```

If all these aren't the issue, you can try to place the static HTML content inside the `index.html` and then inside the `<ang-app></ang-app>` tag. The contents will get replaced anyways once angular is fully loaded. But it will make the initial HTML response with a lot of text :)

Comment: thanks, good idea to place the content inside `<ang-app>` as it will be replaced anyway. Also I will update the nginx :)